# I am Legend: does alternative ending suggest rebuilding of society?

Tags: i-am-legend

The alternate ending as well as earlier scenes show more intelligence in the Dark Seekers than Neville imagined — he seemed really stuck on the idea that they were very diminished mentally even when confronted with some counter-evidence in front of the Vanderbilt statue (the trap).

Now the alternate ending shows the alpha grudgingly forgiving or at least not killing Neville and taking back his mate; but does this imply that the Dark Seekers such as those he leads are firstly, no longer a danger to any hypothetically surviving humans (which Neville doesn't really believe in — he is certain, even after he meets the woman and the boy, that no colony of humans exists, anywhere...) and secondly, bright enough to begin rebuilding (as in Matheson's original book they were — they were just as intelligent as humans because the living ones were actually human, just infected; dead ones were animated corpses but not zombies because they retained some intelligence)?

I saw that the Dark Seekers who attacked Neville's townhouse as still very violent, and their behavior was clearly influenced by the virus. The alpha seemed to communicate with his underlings by screeching and violently throwing them around. (In the lab, this was how he "told" them not to attack Neville.) My sense is that they still live by hunting (I guess animals like deer) and are making no attempts to rebuild. And if they came across a colony of survivors, well, just too bad for the humans. It is kind of surprising then that they would spare Neville, and perhaps this is why the alternate ending was not shown — it does not quite make sense.

Comment: I can go back to the source material to answer this, but the link between the book and the film is... loose, at best.

Comment: @Jontia: I am asking about the movie and specifically the implications of the alternate ending. as i mentioned, they still seem like violent, feral creatures even if they gave Neville a pass that time (which does not quite make sense to me given how they creatures seem to exist).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2007 film *I Am Legend* was the third adaptation of Robert Matheson's 1954 novel of the same name.  The novel practically created the whole vampire/zombie apocalypse genre of horror/SF.  The previous adaptations were [*The Last Man on Earth*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058700/) (1964) starring Vincent Price ([available to watch online on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/lastmanonearth-1964)) and [*The Omega Man*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067525/) starring Charlton Heston.  Both of them are very loose adaptations.  Matheson worked on early iterations of the script for *The Last Man on Earth*, but he was unhappy with the direction that later revisions took and had his name taken off the project.  *The Omega Man* deviated even more from the novel's story.

I mention all this history to illustrate something significant about the 2007 film.  For the first time, the filmmakers decided to keep Matheson's original title.  The previous adaptations had used titles emphasizing their protagonists' roles as the last man left alive.  In contrast, the book title "I Am Legend"—although it is only explained at the very end of the story—is about how Robert Neville is actually, from the point of view of the new vampire society, the last legendary monster.  The name only makes sense in a context where there is a new world of vampires emerging.  So the facts that the film kept the book's title and that the original ending showed the vampires exhibiting some higher-level behavior strongly suggest that they did mean to show that the infected were beginning to rebuild their new world.

Comment: IIRC the alternative had Neville driving off to the colony -- it would be the uninfected who would not just try to rebuild but presumably do something with the infected. I think Neville is bringing a way to prevent further infection among the uninfected or cure those who catch it. But what will they do with the millions of Dark Seekers?